# After loading a popup form background scroll should get hide

Tags: jquery, popup, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scroll

In rails 3.2.9, i am using twitter bootstrap plugin. I am trying to load a popup form, while loading this form background scroll should get hide & after closing this form scroll should work as usual.

I have tried

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

to hide scroll but popup form will display half part(for large form).

```
document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
```

will work properly after the closing popup form.
Even i have tried

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

but this will work when popup form loads but after closing the form scroll will not work for

```
$(window).bind('scroll');
```

this command.

Please suggest some solutions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

try this code..
when popup loads

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

while popup close

```
 $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Comment: this will work for scroll option but $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); piece of code will cause popup form display issue(form will not display properly Eg: if form is large then half part will display at that time scroll option was disabled)

Comment: do one thing smartly. Enable the scroll option for the container that containes the form like $("#idofformcontainer").css( "overflow", "auto");